# How to add Form title to data sent to a Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have multiple Google Forms with identical response fields inputting into a certain Google Sheets, and there is no way of telling them apart other than their names and descriptions. Using Google Apps Script, is there any way I can add the name and/or description of the Google Form into the Sheets, along with everything that is normally added to the Sheets? I did a bit of research about something with "source" but I have no idea how to implement it.

Thanks!

Comment: @Cooper There is only one response sheet that all are feeding into. The issue is not how to find out where a Form is writing to, but how to import a Form's title into a linked Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by going to your form in edit mode selecting "Script Editor" and pasting the below code into the script.  You will need to click on the "Trigger" button (looks like a clock, if you can't find it follow here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Click Add Trigger and select event type "On Form Submit"

```
function writeFormTitle(){
  //Get Form
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  //Get Form's Title
  var formTitle = form.getTitle();

  //Get the Write To Spreadsheet ID where the data will be written to
  var destinationSpreadsheet = form.getDestinationId();

  //Activate that Spreadsheet by the destinationSpreadsheet ID
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheet).getActiveSheet();

  //Find the last column and row
  var writeToColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()+1;
  var writeToRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Write title to Spreadsheet next to submitted data.
  sheet.getRange(writeToRow, writeToColumn, 1, 1).setValue(formTitle);

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering this. This does work for what I asked for this question, my main problem is a two-parter. Could you check out my question [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309018/send-all-google-forms-to-the-same-sheets-gid-with-google-apps-script?noredirect=1)