# Send all Google Forms to the same Sheets gid with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I have a script creating multiple Google Forms that all link to one Google Sheets. I use the function `FormApp.create(name).setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET,destSheetId);` multiple times to accomplish this. This works for the most part, however when I go to the destination Sheets, each Form pastes its information into a different gid of the Sheets. For example, one Form leads to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O8R/edit#gid=0` while another goes to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O8R/edit#gid=1`. Is there any way to either make the Script assign each Form the same gid, or view all the gids in the Sheet at the same time, or anything similar to this?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to use formSubmit to collect all of the data into one spreadsheet.  If you tend to get a high submission rate it may no be possible to keep up.

Comment: @Cooper How would I end up using formSubmit? I'm kind of confused at this point as to how exactly I can solve this issue. Right now, they are all going to the same "Spreadsheet," but the gid number (which I really don't understand what it does) is changing per submission. So every time someone submits something, it goes under a new gid number

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem apparent anyway to have the form write to the same sheet within the same spreadsheet after you've set the destination.  You would probably need to write the entire write To functionality of the responses and then have the actual form hidden.

Alternatively, you can create a "Master Tab" that compiles all the form responses. You would use the below function, updating the sheet and column names with yours to compile all the responses onto a single sheet.  I start at Row2 and hardcode the headers in the master spreadsheet.

```
=SORT({'Form Responses 1'!A2:B;'Form Responses 2'!A2:B;'Form Responses 3'!A2:B},1,0)
```